# Split pdf table columns into separate pages

Tags: pdf, image-processing, ocr

I have an OCRed PDF table. I want to split it into pages, one page per column.

Tabula is not working on this particular document due to a [known issue](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula/issues/647).

Answer (score 1):

Try this program, written by a Thai academic:

https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~somchai/cut2col/